# MacOS Catalina change word delimiter language region setting

Tags: macos, preferences, language, customization

I would like dash (-) to be considered a letter so if I double-click on
`1d18830d-0250-ee03-0c48-6ff9d89dfcff`
the entire string is selected and not just one segment.

It seems you used to be able to select a English Language region:
`United States (Computer)`
to get that behavior but I don't see that choice in preferences anymore.

Is there a way to add that region or copy the "United States" region and modify it for this?

I'm currently running Catalina, but if this changes in Big Sur, tips for it would be welcome too.

Thanks

Answer (score -2):

To choose a region go to System Preferences and then to Language and Region. In Language and Region there is an option to select you region.  Mine was initially set to United States which is what I want.

You can try putting quotes around the name with dashes in it. and see if that works. or convert - to _ and use that.

I'm running Big Sur on an iMac.